# Error to_string not declared in this scope ¿Cómo solucionarlo?

Tags: c, dev-c++

Compilo este código y me sale el siguiente error, busque y me dice que es una configuración del compilador pero lo reconfiguro a  lo  vuelvo a compilar y me sale `Error to_string not declared in this scope` lo cambié a C++ 11 y no me funciona ya incluí la biblioteca `string` no se que mas hacer para solucionarlo ¿alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

```
   #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    void ip_aleatory(){
    
     
        volatile int n1[10+1];
        volatile int n2[10+1];
        volatile int n3[10+1];
        volatile int n4[10+1];
            
        srand(time(NULL)); 
    
        for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
        {
    
          n1[i] = 0 + rand() % (255); 
          n2[i] = 0 + rand() % (255); 
          n3[i] = 0 + rand() % (255); 
          n4[i] = 0 + rand() % (255); 
      
        }
    
        string  IPs[10]; 
    
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    
    
         IPs[i] = to_string(n1[i]) + '.' +
                  to_string(n2[i]) + '.' +
                  to_string(n3[i]) + '.' +
                  to_string(n4[i]) ;
    
       }
    
      for (const auto &IP : IPs){
            
        cout << IP << '\n';
            
       }

  

}
int main (){


 
 
 ip_aleatory();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Estas poniendo que la función `int ip_aleatory(int ip)` retorna un `int`, pero no tiene valor de retorno. Agrega un `return [algo]` o bien declara la función como `void`

Comment: @aeportugal Podrías ponerlo como respuesta.

Comment: cambia el nombre de las librerias porque en C++ no se usan los .h como estandar; cualquier cosa heredada del C contiene la letra c al principio por ejemplo NO ES `<stdio.h>` SE HACE `<cstdio>`, otro problema es tu compilador, en Windows el MINGW es pesimo porque esta descontinuado. Pasa a visual studio para evitarte estos problemas tecnicos y porfavor lee https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask para que mejores tu pregunta

Comment: Para hacer capturas de pantalla parciales recomiendo _lightshot_.

Comment: @ArtEze windows 10 viene con una herramienta de recortes incluida la combinacion es TeclaWindows + Shift + S

Answer (score 2):

Añade lo siguiente en la parte superior de tu código:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L || (defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER >= 1900)
#else
    #error "C++11 is not supported";
#endif
```

Si no te tira el error `"C++11 is not supported"`, probablemente tu compilador
no soporte completamente C++11.

En mi maquina tu codigo compila correctamente, probe con `cl`, `gcc` (el que usa
tu IDE), y `clang`. Asi que el problema es con tu entorno de desarrollo. Mi
recomendacion seria dejar de usar DevC++. Es un IDE viejisimo con un monton de
bugs. Si estas en Windows lo optimo seria que uses Visual Studio. Si Visual
Studio es muy pesado para tu maquina, usa vs code con clang o gcc.